# Custom Workflow Settings with Visual Studio

Tags: workflow

I have been searching for days on resources to read or tutorials to follow regarding custom SP 2010 workflows created in Visual Studio and **aspx pages used for setting values**. I have no problem creating and deploying the workflow itself. What I cannot seem to find any information on, and it could be I am just using the wrong terms in my searches, is how to add a page so various settings can be specified when the workflow is added to a given list or library.

I notice that when you go to List Settings --> Workflow Settings, then select a workflow from the template list, some of the workflows show an OK button and the others (like the Three-state workflow) show a **Next** button. Clicking Next takes you to a page (different for each workflow) where the person adding the workflow can set values used during the workflow execution.

Any information with this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms481192.aspx

Comment: Association Form. I figured it was a terminology thing. Been going back and force so many times the last few weeks trying to learn new concepts for a custom SharePoint solution I think my brain has become mush. Thank you.